# Hello, it is posible to increase the number of simultaniously ajax requests in a browser?

Tags: ajax

Hello I have to make like 200 simultaneous Ajax requests the mysql that takes around of 30 seconds every query.

But the browser only allows to run 6 at one time.

Its is posible to  increase the number of simultaniously ajax requests in a browser?

Thanks!

Comment: Only for yourself (your own browser)? Or for other people (that visit your web site)?

Comment: And are you sure you want to run 200 queries that take 30 seconds each all at once against your poor database?

Comment: only for my own browser

Comment: There seems to be a setting for Firefox: https://support.mozilla.org/de/questions/992338

Comment: That is. About:config network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-server = 10 Thanks Thilo